# php mapi extension

Tags: php

I want to install PHP MAPI Extension , am not find find the plugin any where ,

Please tell me mapi plugin download URL ,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this MAPI extension is part of the [Zafara Community Edition](http://www.zarafa.com/download-community).

You need to download the package for your distro, or the source package. I'm not sure how compatible this is with stock PHP, see the [requirements](http://doc.zarafa.com/6.40/Administrator_Manual/en-US/html/_installing.html) in their manual.