# PHP client for MS Exchange Mail

Tags: php, exchange-server

I am developing a simple PHP mail client for MS Exchange Mail:

- To send out emails with attachments via MS Exchange Mail
- To receive email with attachments from MS Exchange Mail

What method should i use ? is there any open source library which coveres the requirements above ?

thanks.

Comment: So far, the only answer I have found is this. <http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/exchange_webdav_examples.php> <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148744/php-mapi-extension> <http://code.google.com/p/php-ews/>

Answer (score 2):

Use `Zend_Mail` classes , it would do all mail functions you need

it support IMAP - POP - SMTP - MBOX

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html -

Comment: i need to send/receive emails(attachments) with MS Exchange Mail(external mail server). Zend_Mail does not support it ?

Comment: yes you can , consult the documentation  for more information